# Problem with connection between sim7070g into NB-IoT

Tags: module

I have a module SIM7070g and I can’t connect this module and an addition uno into nb-Iot

My results of Serial monitor are :

```
AT + CPIN = “0954”
Ok
+CPIN: READY

SMS Ready 

AT + CGDCONT=1, “IP”, “iot”
Ok
```

AT + COPS=1,2, “20201”, 20
ERROR

What are your thoughts ???